# Apache Ant Failing to Make Directory for OpenIMSCore's FHoSS

Tags: xml, apache, ant, mkdir

I am trying to compile a physical version of OpenIMSCore on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Linux Computer. I've followed the instructions as specified [here at cnd's website](http://www.openimscore.org/documentation/installation-guide/). To verify that I have all of the necessary required programs and libraries, [here is a text file outlining all of the different versions of the required programs I am using](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bwr1M0WsOOs1X1BkWFlvYURBV28). This problem seems to be similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401595/ant-build-fails-with-no-visible-errors), except mine is failing to make directories, his fails to find them.

To ensure I provide the optimal amount of information available, here is the
debug information after I preformed an `ant clean` operation in the terminal:

```
/opt/OpenIMSCore/FHoSS$ ant compile -d
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on April 8 2014
Trying the default build file: build.xml
Buildfile: /opt/OpenIMSCore/FHoSS/build.xml
Adding reference: ant.PropertyHelper
Detected Java version: 1.7 in: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
Detected OS: Linux
Adding reference: ant.ComponentHelper
Setting ro project property: ant.file -> /opt/OpenIMSCore/FHoSS/build.xml
Setting ro project property: ant.file.type -> file
Adding reference: ant.projectHelper
Adding reference: ant.parsing.context
Adding reference: ant.targets
parsing buildfile /opt/OpenIMSCore/FHoSS/build.xml with URI = file:/opt/OpenIMSCore/FHoSS/build.xml
Setting ro project property: ant.project.name -> FHoSS Project
Adding reference: FHoSS Project
Setting ro project property: ant.project.default-target -> compile
Setting ro project property: ant.file.FHoSS Project -> /opt/OpenIMSCore/FHoSS/build.xml
Setting ro project property: ant.file.type.FHoSS Project -> file
Project base dir set to: /opt/OpenIMSCore/FHoSS
 +Target: 
 +Target: init
 +Target: compile
 +Target: jars
 +Target: config
 +Target: script
 +Target: deploy
 +Target: jdoc
 +Target: example
 +Target: clean
 +Target: cleanall
 +Target: deb
Adding reference: ant.LocalProperties
parsing buildfile jar:file:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml with URI = jar:file:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml from a zip file
 [property] Loading /opt/OpenIMSCore/FHoSS/build.properties
Setting project property: path.deploy -> deploy
Setting project property: path.src -> /opt/OpenIMSCore/FHoSS/src
Setting project property: path.srcweb -> /opt/OpenIMSCore/FHoSS/src-web
Setting project property: path.build -> /opt/OpenIMSCore/FHoSS/bin
Setting project property: path.doc -> /opt/OpenIMSCore/FHoSS/docs
Setting project property: path.webdest -> /opt/OpenIMSCore/FHoSS/deploy/webapps/hss.web.console
Setting project property: path.log -> /opt/OpenIMSCore/FHoSS/deploy/logs
Setting project property: path.config -> /opt/OpenIMSCore/FHoSS/deploy
Setting project property: path.script -> /opt/OpenIMSCore/FHoSS/deploy
Setting project property: path.example -> /opt/OpenIMSCore/FHoSS/deploy/examples
Setting project property: compile.debug -> true
Setting project property: compile.deprecation -> true
Setting project property: compile.optimize -> true
Adding reference: compile.classpath
Setting ro project property: ant.project.invoked-targets -> compile
Attempting to create object of type org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor
Adding reference: ant.executor
Build sequence for target(s) `compile' is [init, compile]
Complete build sequence is [init, compile, jars, config, script, deploy, example, jdoc, deb, cleanall, clean, ]

init:
Setting project property: DSTAMP -> 20170707
Setting project property: TSTAMP -> 1523
Setting project property: TODAY -> July 7 2017

BUILD FAILED
/opt/OpenIMSCore/FHoSS/build.xml:36: Directory /opt/OpenIMSCore/FHoSS/bin creation was not successful for an unknown reason
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Mkdir.execute(Mkdir.java:70)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)

Total time: 0 seconds
```

And here is the build.xml file provided by cnd: [I put it on Google Drive due to its size and the fact that this post is already lengthy as is](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bwr1M0WsOOs1NEJQZnhZTFFHSkE). The point at which Apache Ant supposedly fails is at line 36, the mkdir command:

```xml
    <target name="init">
        <tstamp/>
        <mkdir dir="${path.build}" />
    </target>
```

I hope this is clear enough for someone to help me. I am fairly new to Apache Ant, so bear with me, but I can do my best to provide whatever else may be needed to debug this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is was nothing wrong with Apache Ant nor the build.xml.

As recommended by [this forum post](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43888), I was to create a directory on my own. I then realized that the folder that I was compiling in:

```
privateusername@privatecomputername-Dimension-E521:/opt/OpenIMSCore/FHoSS$
```

Since I am in the ***"opt"*** folder, this requires that I am either using the root account or using "sudo" when initiating the "ant compile" command, especially if the xml file contains "mkdir" commands. I hope this is helpful to anyone experiencing issues with OpenIMSCore or with Ant.

Lesson learned, always know what the properties of the folder you are working in before running Ant: *you might need root privileges in order to preform certain tasks.*